# Add Custom Page to the existing module

Tags: php, magento, frontend

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

i have a extension with the name **Mall/Brand**

I want to add on custom page to that module for that i wrote like this

**brand.xml**

```
<brand_manufacturer_selectbrand>
      <reference name="content">
           <block type="brand/manufacturer" name="manufacturer_selectbrand" template="mall/brand/manufacturer/selectbrand.phtml"/>
      </reference>
</brand_manufacturer_selectbrand>
```

**ManufacturerController.php**

```
public function selectbrandAction() {
    $this->loadLayout( array('default','brand_manufacturer_selectbrand'));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle( Mage::helper('manufacturer')->__('Selected Brands'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

In side Block folder **Manufacturer.php**

```
<?php
   class Mall_Brand_Block_Manufacturer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
       public function getManufacturer() { 
         $manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_manufacturer');
        if($manufacturer == null) {
            $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $manufacturer = Mage::getModel('brand/manufacturer')->load($id);
        }
        return $manufacturer;
    }
}
?>
```

for frontend **selectbrand.phtml**

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

just for checking only

I tried like this in address bar

```
http://localhost/mage12/index.php/selectbrand
```

its showing **Whoooops ... our bad**

any thing wrong i did here ?

any ideas ?

Comment: you need to declare the frontname: search for Allan Storm's tutorial

Answer (score 0):

check you frontend name in etc/config.xml

then try below url

```
http://localhost/mage12/index.php/**frontend_name_in_config**/manufacturer/selectbrand
```

i think you frontend name is brand so below url will work

```
http://localhost/mage12/index.php/brand/manufacturer/selectbrand
```

hope this will help you